# Making DNS permanent in Docker's containers

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, docker

I have container1, I have edited the `/etc/resolv.conf` and put `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `ping google.com`. It works fine.
But I need to make this permanent, when I restart my docker's container using

```
sudo docker restart container1
```

I can't ping google.com anymore through my container.

**Note:**

I have tried what they have posted from 3-7 years ago on here. It doesn't work.
My Ubuntu release is 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

As explained under [DNS services](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services), a container inherits the resolv.conf file from the host by default.

```
[root@testvm ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.1.1

[root@testvm ~]# docker run -it ubuntu bash

root@a0a0d88f6db8:/# mount|grep resolv.conf
/dev/mapper/centos-root on /etc/resolv.conf type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)

root@79c567a830b4:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

To add the DNS nameserver configuration inside the container, you then have two options:

1. Add the DNS nameserver(s) to the resolv.conf file on the host.
2. Start the container with one or more `--dns` options, explicitly
   specifying the DNS nameservers.

Here is the `--dns` option in use:

```
[root@testvm ~]# docker run -it --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 ubuntu bash
root@3ae155186997:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

This option also persists across a restart, as demonstrated with an nginx image below:

```
[root@testvm ~]# docker run -d -p 8080:80 --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 nginx
97f76bedfad8173bb38e4e83f898b61be6c8587775736576d09c94ebaf5d5d36

[root@testvm ~]# docker exec -it 97f76bedfad8173bb38e4e83f898b61be6c8587775736576d09c94ebaf5d5d36 bash

root@97f76bedfad8:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

root@97f76bedfad8:/# exit
exit

[root@testvm ~]# docker restart 97f76bedfad8173bb38e4e83f898b61be6c8587775736576d09c94ebaf5d5d36
97f76bedfad8173bb38e4e83f898b61be6c8587775736576d09c94ebaf5d5d36

[root@testvm ~]# docker exec -it 97f76bedfad8173bb38e4e83f898b61be6c8587775736576d09c94ebaf5d5d36 bash
root@97f76bedfad8:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```